# How to open in visual studio 2008 the c++ or C?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

I want to write program using C in Visual studio 2008. But I have no idea how to start, what should I select so that i can create C program

File->New project->"other language C++".

Or

File->New->new file ?

Comment: Have you even considered trying to check the Visual Studio documentation? -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4457htyc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Hi,i read the link that you gave to me,i just want to have some clarify about this "You can also use application wizards ",is this custom wizard ?

Comment: Read not only this one page, but follow the links to learn about details. Click "Visual C++ Projects" to go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6765tta0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx You get "application wizard for the following project types" exaplained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your wording, I think you're probably looking to develop native CLI (Command Line Interface) applications, in which case you want "Win32 Console Application"

Note that any project type with CLR in the name is not true C/C++, it's the .NET managed implementation of C++. Likewise, anything with ATL or MFC in the name is a case of "if you don't know what it is, you don't need it."

Hopefully that will help narrow it down for you, but you probably want the one I suggested anyway.

Comment: Just noting that the acronym "CLI" as it is used here may confuse the OP because C++/CLI is MS's term for managed C++.

Comment: Wow, really not sure how that one passed me by but thanks for the correction. Seems like a bit of a cheeky naming convention on Microsoft's part!